# Get one of the element of the Children in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to get one of the element and trigger a click event. But since I have 4 of the element with same name I am trying to pin point it by this code.

```
cy.contains('*Real Estate Assets').parent().children().get('.formAddBtn.icon-btn.primary').click()
```

Even after pin pointing the section I am trying to click on, its still showing 4 other element that has same class name.

[Here is a image of dev console[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Y7w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the screenshot doesn't show the place where the buttons should be I can't completely be sure of this answer. But I did this assumption: Real Estate Assets, Assets and 2 more all have the button `.formAddBtn.icon-btn.primary`. And you want to select the button for Real Estate Assets. If that assumption is correct this should work:

```js
cy.contains('*Real Estate Assets')
  .parent()
  .find('.formAddBtn.icon-btn.primary')
  .click()
```

By using `find()` Cypress will search within the code yielded in the previous `get()`. So it narrows the search down to everything below the parent of *Real Estate Assets.